# jQuery template access array object member

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, templates

I'm looking to figure out how to access in a jQuery template items from a JSON result that look like this.

```
[
 {"appLayerId":"6002",
  "name":"US",
  "description":"test",
  "dataSource":"POINT",
  "status":{
      "status":"Success",
      "reason":"None",
      "otherInfo":null
      }
  }
 ]
```

I thought inside the template it would just be `${appLayerId}` but that doesn't seem to work.

-- UPDATE

In case it helps someone to help me, I'm trying to follow this code on jsFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/iainjmitchell/kRRXC/
The difference from that example is my URL to get the JSON and my names in the jquery template part. My json is above as I mentioned in the original post. Like I said, I can see the json response in firebug, and there are no page errors, but I'm not seeing any text on the page from the template. Hopefully this helps someone to help me. Thank you.

-- UPDATE 2

I'm obviously missing something simple here. You asked to see the code. Like I said, it is exactly the same as that example. Here is what is different.

twitterUrl: "http://localhost/Services.Administration/Maintenance.svc/layers?Fmt=application/json",

Then in the template part I have this div.

```
 <div class="source">
    <label>${name}, ${appLayerId}</label>
 </div>
```

When you say, just access the properties like that of an object. What is the object where I could just do, objectName.appLayerId inside the template. Not sure exactly what you're saying, sorry.

Hope this helps you to help me get this sorted out. Thanks for your help.

-- UPDATE 3

Looking into this further... I did a a console.dir(this.model); in the addAll function. In firebug the console shows the "models" as being empty. Why would that be? Again, all I've changed is the URL from that example.

```
           addAll: function(){
                var el = this.el;
                el.hide().empty();
                console.dir(this.model);
                this.model.each(function(tweet){
                    var view = new TweetView({model: tweet});
                    el.append(view.render().el);
                });
                el.slideDown(500);
            }
```

Comment: I think it's an object. It's coming in via a Ajax call using backbone. I can see the response in firebug so I know it's coming through. I think I'm just not accessing the values right, not sure. I tried $[name] as well thinking that might do it, but no.

Comment: post all the pertinent code you are usig that isn't working. A link to a sample you are trying to "follow" doesn't do anyone any good. It works, yours doesn't

Answer (score 0):

having your string representation of object in a variable you can use `$.parseJSON()` to convert it to js object and then use it as always you do.

```
  var result = "[
 {'appLayerId':'6002',
  'name':'US',
  'description':'test',
  'dataSource':'POINT',
  'status':{
      'status':'Success',
      'reason':'None',
      'otherInfo':null
      }
  }
 ]";

 var resultObject = $.parseJSON(result);
 var subObject1 = resultObject[0];
 var appLayerId1 = subObject1.appLayerId;
```

hope this help.

Comment: if the JSON is coming in via jQuery AJAX it wouldn't be a string , it would already be an object ...this seems confusing

Comment: It's an object. It's coming in via an Ajax backbone call. Maybe I'm just missing something simple with how to get at the values, not sure. Like I said ${name} didn't seem to do it.

Comment: Any further help from anyone?

Comment: @charlietfl if it is an object then why not simply use it's properties like an object.

Comment: @BehnamEsmaili   that is my point. Not sure where the string entered into picture